# PHP pthreads memory issue

Tags: php, multithreading, memory, pthreads

I am developing a networking application where I listen on a port and create a new socket and thread when a new connection request arrives; the architecture is working well but we are facing severe memory issues.

The problem is that even if I create a single thread, it does the work but the memory keeps on increasing.

To demonstrate the problem please review the following code where we start one thread of a class whose duty it to print a thread ID and a random number infinitely.

```
class ThreadWorker extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        while(1) {
            echo $this->getThreadId()." => ".rand(1,1000)."\r\n";
        }
    }
}

$th = new ThreadWorker();
$th->start();
```

I am developing it on Windows OS and when I open the task manager the PHP.exe memory usage keeps on increasing until the system becomes unresponsive.

Please note that the PHP script is executed from command line:

```
PHP.exe pthreads-test.php
```

Comment: Have you tested the code in cases of creating 0 and 1 threads? How does php.exe perform then? (just change the top value of the for loop)

Comment: @Claudix Yes exactly same results if I just create one thread instead of 100. Let me alter the example.

Comment: Now try to leave empty the `while(1)` loop of the thread (i.e. remove the echo command). What happens then?

Comment: Also try to sleep for a while after echoing a line. Perhaps running that echo too fast may lead into an incorrect memory management (i.e. garbage collector may be slow compared to the speed of those echos)

Comment: After removing the Echo it stays on same memory limit and processor usage 100%. I just replaced echo with file_put_contents() and the same issue of memory happens again. Let me add a Sleep function and then test again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think the problem is that the thread loop is highly CPU consuming. Avoid such that code. If you just want to echo a message, I recommend putting a `sleep()` instruction after. Example:

```
class ThreadWorker extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        while(1) {
            echo $this->getThreadId()." => ".rand(1,1000)."\r\n";
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

It seems [there's a way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) to force garbage collection in PHP. On the other hand, sleep() is not a proper way to stabilize CPU use. Normally threads do things like reading from files, sockets or pipes, i.e., they often perform I/O operations which are normally blocking (i.e. they pause the thread until data is I/O operation is possible). This behaviour inherently yields the CPU and other resources to other threads, thus stabilizing the whole system.

Comment: Adding Sleep(1) stablizes the thread memory and processor usage, but I am thinking would it be good to sleep for 1 second in a Networking app where high latency is required? Is there any way to explicitly call PHP garbage collector from within the thread?

Comment: Not sure whether that's possible or not. Sorry.

Comment: I've found a way to force garbage collection: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

Comment: @asim: if you want to yield to other tasks with a finer level of control, try `usleep()`.

Comment: You answer to a CPU issue but what about memory issues ? My Threads seem consuming infinite memory but there are limited to 50.

Comment: For a trivial faster execution you can change `sleep(1)` with `usleep($interval = 16000)` where $interval represents Windows Timer Resolution which by default is 15.6ms on Windows 7 ... I usualy put it around 16.667ms (~16000 microseconds) to get ~60 updates per second for  calculations/work that need this refresh frequency